# How to use XML Views? Any examples?

Tags: sapui5

I need to build a page in xml views sapui5 but I'm not able to find a complete list of the elements available in XML views, so I don't have a full knowledge of XML Views. Where can i find the list of controls and example available.

Comment: This question shows that there was little to no research done. Since the UI5 documentation can be found by a single google search, I'm voting to close this question. Asking for other external resources (blog posts, books, and other references) is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Well.. actually your question has nothing to do with XML views... you are asking for the documentation which can be easily found on Google. In any case:

SAPUI5 - https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f292806f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070

OpenUI5 - https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f292806f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070

Every control you can create in a JavaScript context can also be created in an XML view. Just the notation is different. Control names are tags and control attributes are tag attributes on XML views.

Under the ["Samples"](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/controls) tab in the Demo Kit, you have many examples of controls in XML views and you are able to see the source code by clicking on a single button.

Answer (score 1):

The Explored link [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html) provides a full list of all available UI5(sap.m) components. Select any sample & click on the Show Code button at the top right. You will find the associated view files in xml along with the controller js files.

Answer (score 0):

All SAPUI5 controls/elements can be used in XML views, for that matter in all view types. You can refer the [API Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html) for a detailed list of UI controls.

Different view types are supported to help developers from different programming backgrounds.